# QCheckBox to check/uncheck all QCheckboxes from another class in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qcheckbox

I have two QWidget classes: Widget1 and Widget2, and I would like to have a QCheckBox in the first class (Widget1) that can check/uncheck all the QcheckBoxes generated by the second class (Widget2). Is there a way to do this?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

```
class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, ids):
        super().__init__()
        self.ids = ids  # ids is a list of list [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], ..., [n, n] generated elsewhere in the code 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.widget1_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.Widget1_Layout)

        self.master_checkbox = QCheckBox("Select all")
        self.master_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.selectAll)
        self.widget1_layout.addWidget(self.master_checkbox)

        for i, id in enumerate(self.ids):
            self.singleID_checkbox = Widget2(self, i, id)
            self.widget1_layout.addWidget(self.singleID_checkbox)

     def selectAll(self):
        if self.master_checkbox.isChecked():
            function_that_check_all_Widget2_checkboxes()
        else:
            function_that_UNcheck_all_Widget2_checkboxes()



class Widget2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, i, id, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.i = i
        self.id = id
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.singleIDcheckbox_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.singleIDcheckbox = QCheckBox(str(self.id))
        self.singleIDcheckbox_layout.addWidget(self.singleIDcheckbox, self.i, 0)
```

The two functions

```
function_that_check_all_Widget2_checkboxes()
```

and

```
function_that_UNcheck_all_Widget2_checkboxes()
```

do not exist.

They are are here as examples to better present my problem, as I guess that this is where I should put some code to do what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Your question is confusing: you want to change the state of the checkbox in Widget2 based on the checkbox in Widget1, but in your code you're connecting to the `stateChanged` signal for the Widget2.

Comment: Also note that: 1. the widget argument of a QLayout constructor already sets that layout: if you do `QVBoxLayout(self)`, you don't need to use `setLayout`. 2. names of variables and functions (including instance attributes and methods) should **always** start with a lower case letter, as only classes and constants normally start with upper case letters: this is a **very** important aspect of code readability. Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I have edited my code, the stateChanged signal for Widget2 is something unrelated to my question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sorry but I'm still a bit puzzled: you said that you want a *single* checkbox in Widget1 that toggles all checkboxes in Widget2, but you are creating *more* checkboxes in Widget1 and there's only one in Widget2.

Comment: Thank you for trying to understand my problem @musicamante. I have again edited my code to enhance clarity. I do not want a single checkbox in Widget1, but actually a 'master' checkbox that could check/uncheck all the Widget2-type checkboxes.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, now I get it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add each widget to a list whenever you're creating them, then check/uncheck them according to the "master" state.

Note that:

1. when creating multiple objects there's no use in setting them as instance members: the purpose of an instance attribute is to have a persistent reference to an object, if you continously overwrite that reference you lose that benefit;
2. most signals provide arguments, especially those relating "changes"; calling `isChecked()` is unnecessary, as `stateChanged` already returns the current state, you just need to add the argument to the function;
3. unless you're requiring a *tristate* checkbox, the correct signal is `toggled` (which returns a `bool` state), not the `stateChanged` (which returns a `Qt.CheckState` flag that has 2 for the checked state);

```
class Widget1(QWidget):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        self.widget1_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.master_checkbox = QCheckBox("Select all")
        self.master_checkbox.toggled.connect(self.selectAll)
        self.widget1_layout.addWidget(self.master_checkbox)

        self.checkboxes = []
        for i, id in enumerate(self.ids):
            singleID_checkbox = Widget2(self, i, id)
            self.widget1_layout.addWidget(singleID_checkbox)
            self.checkboxes.append(singleID_checkbox)

    def selectAll(self, state):
        for check in self.checkboxes:
            check.setChecked(state)


class Widget2(QWidget):
    # ...
    def setChecked(self, state):
        self.singleIDcheckbox.setChecked(state)
```

Note that, since you're using a specialized class, you *could* also use `findChildren`, which returns all child objects that are instances of the specified class:

```
    def selectAll(self, state):
        for check in self.findChildren(Widget2):
            check.setChecked(state)
```

Use the above with care, though, as by default it looks recursively through the whole object tree, so using a list is still a better solution.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for your rapidity and help with this!